# Forcing update of a throttled computed property

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I have a form with a text input bound to computed property (containing a time). After a user enters a value, it is parsed into a integer value containing the total minutes.

Since this is not a trivial function (there are many ways of formatting time), the property has a [Throttle Extender](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/throttle-extender.html).

This all works fine, the problem is when the user enters a value and immediately hits a save button, obviously the throttled value is not evaluated yet.

```
self.totalMinutes = ko.observable(0);
self.totalMinutesValue = ko.computed({
    read: function() { 
        return MinutesToFormat(self.totalMinutes()); 
    } 
    write: function(value) { 
        self.totalMinutes(FormatToMinutes(value)); 
    } 
}).extend({ throttle: 250 });

self.Save = function() {
    // Send self.totalMinutes() to server, need to ensure the throttled 
    // computed has been written.
}
```

Is there a simple way to force the property to update immediately from the send method? I could add a `setTimeout` but that is of course far from ideal.

Comment: I have not used throttle much but in 3.1 i believe it is recommended that you instead use the rateLimit extender. Maybe this will solve the issue? - http://www.knockmeout.net/2014/03/knockout-3-1-released.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the rateLimiter could infact solve this problem.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/rateLimit-observable.html

> "**Writes to observables are not delayed; the observable’s value is
>   updated right away. For writable computed observables, this means that
>   the write function is always run right away.**
>
> All change notifications are delayed, including when calling
>   valueHasMutated manually. This means you can’t use valueHasMutated to
>   force a rate-limited observable to notify an un-changed value.
>
> The default rate-limit method is different from the throttle
>   algorithm. To match the throttle behavior, use the
>   notifyWhenChangesStop method."
>
> **Evaluation of a rate-limited computed observable isn’t rate-limited;
>   it will re-evaluate if you read its value.**